# How do I compile "POSIX Threads for Windows" using MINGW

Tags: c++, c, makefile, compilation

I download *POSIX Threads for Windows* source code from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w/files/.
Unzip it. In the directory, there several files for make:

*Bmakefile*   *Makefile*   *Nmakefile*  *GNUmakefile.in*

If directly run *mingw32-make*, I get

```
Makefile:123: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Open *makefile* in editor, the first line told me:

> This makefile is compatible with MS nmake

Maybe it is not a standard makefile file?
So, I just delete *makefile*. and change the name of  *GNUmakefile.in* into *makefile*. Then run 'mingw32-make' again, I get

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, @RC@ --help, ...) failed.
mingw32-make: makefile:112: pipe: No error
makefile:180: @srcdir@/common.mk: No such file or directory
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target '@srcdir@/common.mk'.  Stop.
```

I don't really know how make actualy working. But if I want to compile it, what should I do?

===========================================================
UPDATE

There is *README* file, and it suggest how to build using MINGW. But seems all it told(like  *autoheader*  *autoconf* ) are not windows commands.

> ### Building with MinGW
>
> NOTE: All building and testing is done using makefiles. We use the
> native make system for each toolchain, which is 'make' in this case.
>
> We have found that Mingw builds of the GCE library variants can fail
> when run on 64 bit systems, believed to be due to the DWARF2 exception
> handling being a 32 bit mechanism. The GC variants are fine. MinGW64
> offers SJLJ or SEH exception handling so choose one of those.
>
> From the source directory:
>
> run 'autoheader' to rewrite the config.h file
> run 'autoconf' to rewrite the GNUmakefiles (library and tests)
> run './configure' to create config.h and GNUmakefile.
> run 'make' without arguments to list possible targets.
>
> E.g.
>
> $ autoheader
> $ autoconf
> $ ./configure
> $ make realclean all-tests

===========================================================
UPDATE
Seems the MINGW I downloaded already contains pthreads library. I don't need to compile it now.

Comment: *change the name of GNUmakefile.in* this is not how it's done. .in files are usually inputs for a configure script. Do you have one in that folder? Is there a README file there?

Comment: An error like `Makefile:123: missing separator` or similar, is typically because there are commands in rules that are indented by space instead of tabs. The `make` command is sensitive to that, all indentations *must* be using actual tabs.

Comment: And please [edit] your question to rewrite your title to be a short summary of your actual problem. Right now it's totally unrelated to the problems you're having.

Comment: The MinGW installation manager has an option for installing `pthread` which is already built and configured for MinGW. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036686/use-pthreads-in-mingw-in-win7

Comment: Is compiling them yourself a must? There are many MinGW distributions including them out of the box, e.g. https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: Just use Mingw64 instead.